# I want to create a new column which categorizes values from another column but i get a ValueError after applying lambda

Tags: pandas, dataframe, if-statement, lambda, apply

I want to create a new column which categorizes the values in the manufacturer column to their contintent of origen e.g. Europe for Volkswagen. The values in the manufacturer columns are objects.

Im trying to use the following function:

```py
def  func(region):
    if auto2['manufacturer'] == 'Audi':
        return 'Europa'
    elif auto2['manufacturer'] == 'Land Rover':
        return 'Europa'
    elif auto2['manufacturer'] == 'Volkswagen':
        return 'Europa'
    elif auto2['manufacturer'] == 'Chevrolet':
        return 'Verenigde Staten'
    elif auto2['manufacturer'] == 'Jeep':
        return 'Verenigde Staten'
    elif auto2['manufacturer'] == 'Dodge':
        return 'Verenigde Staten'
    elif auto2['manufacturer'] == 'Ford':
        return 'Verenigde Staten'
    elif auto2['manufacturer'] == 'Lincoln':
        return 'Verenigde Staten'
    elif auto2['manufacturer'] == 'Mercury':
        return 'Verenigde Staten'
    elif auto2['manufacturer'] == 'Pontiac':
        return 'Verenigde Staten'
    else: 
        return 'Asia'

auto2['Region'] = auto2['manufacturer'].apply(lambda x: region)
```

Defining the function works fine but when I execute the apply function i get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Is there any way I can fix my code, or is there a better way to make a new column which categorizes values from another column?

Comment: You typically need to call x on the other side of the colon in your lambda function. I'm not sure I'm seeing `region` defined in your code either, or that you're calling `func()` anywhere, either. Probably more importantly, I can't think of an implementation of `func()` that would work, so I think it might be a misunderstanding of how python functions work or how pandas works, but I'm not 100% clear on what the intent is with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a much easier way to do this. First, define a dictionary (but with all of the values and not just these four):

```
manufacturer_regions = {
    'Audi': 'Europa',
    'Land Rover': 'Europa',
    'Jeep': 'Verenigde Staten',
    'Dodge': 'Verenigde Staten'
}
```

Then just apply it to the `manufacturer` column:

```
auto2['region'] = auto2.manufacturer.apply(lambda x: manufacturer_regions[x])
```

Comment: haha i dont know how lol, i cant upvote yet because my reputation is not high enough

Comment: Can you check the answer as correct? It's a green checkmark next to the answer.